# Getting WMS address from ArcGIS Online service?

Tags: arcgis-online, google-maps-api, usgs

Was wondering if there was a way to get a WMS service address/feature/functionality from an ArcGIS online service, to provide Tile functionality?

i.e. If I want to use this ArcGIS online service (assuming all licenses are gotten)  https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/  In a (Android) Google Maps API as a Tile Service, how would I go about getting the correct URL to use to point to the service?

Comment: The tile service is the WMTS link in the page you reference.   Note that a WMS is not a tile service, though it often used like one by clients.

Comment: @nmtoken   You are correct - I was working with an ex-developer's code, and thanks to the answer below, I found out that it was being used wrong. Once I found the WMTS service link and read up on it, that was how it was supposed to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use WMS it's slow you want tiles. ESRI has XYZ tile URL for that cached map server https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png 
Just add /tile/z/y/x.ing
Note ESRI has Y AND X placeholders reversed compared to standard GOOGLE XYZ or TMS tile server URL. VECTOR TILE basemap is also available and your vector tiles just use flat instead of indexed for compatibility with other mapping clients

Comment: Thank. You. This helped me make the connection that I needed to look for services that support WMTS. While it's not seamless (url difference like you mentioned), once implemented it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

A service needs to be published with WMS enabled in order to allow WMS tiles https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/wms-services.ht

There is also a tool called [GMap4](https://mappingsupport.com/p/gmap4-arcgis-layers-on-google-maps.html) for viewing esri layers in Google Maps.